# java get missing field

Tags: java, field

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a book named "Java is Fun" with 200 in stock costing 55.00 each.  The stock number is 1234
    Book javafun = new Book("Java is Fun", 200, 55.00, 1234);
    //print out the book using the toString() method
    System.out.println (javafun.toString());

    //create a book calling the empty constructor.
    Book newbook2 = new Book();
    //set the title to "Databases R Us"
    String title = "Databases R Us";
    //set the number in stock to 50
    int numInStock = 50;
    // set the cost each to $35.00
    double cost = 35.00;  <------ this 
    // set the stock number to 5555
    int stockNum = 5555; 
    //print out the book.
    System.out.println(newbook2.toString());
    //change the price to $55.00
    double cost = 55.00;  <-- and this gives me duplicate error
    //print out the book
    System.out.println (newbook2.toString());

}
```

how would i do the steps below the space?

i kind of did what i think it should be but it gives me i have duplicate . and the output is not coming out right

output should be:

Java is Fun with id number 1234 has 200 books in stock costing $55.00 each.

Database R Us with id number 5555 has 50 books in stock costing $35.00 each.

Database R Us with id number 5555 has 50 books in stock costing $55.00 each.

Comment: change the price would just require `cost = 55.00;` (without the `double` in front). For the other "output is not coming right", the `Book`'s code is required. And what is the expected output?

Comment: it would help us to help u if u could provide us with class Book. :D Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling setter methods in my main application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603353/calling-setter-methods-in-my-main-application)

Answer (score 1):

You have a duplicate local variable. `double cost = 55.00;` will cause a syntax error.

Judging by the comment in your program, it looks like you just want to change the value, don't prefix the variable name with a data type.

i.e.  `cost = 55.00;`

If you mean to be changing the cost associated with a specific Book object, as another user has suggested.. just go `book1.setCost/Title/Whatever(...)` I'm assuming that in your Book class you have setter methods and your variables aren't public.

Comment: if i do cost = 55.00; it gives me error cannot resolve to a variable

Comment: @adrianhmartinez, that is because you clear out any variable with name `cost`. Please have a look at my answer and see how you can change the values for the class members.

Comment: You are just changing the value of a local variable that's in the same scope. If you haven't changed anything else there isn't a reason you should get that error. Do you mean to be going something like: newbook2.setCost(...)? Use the set methods that I'm assuming are in your Book class to set the objects values

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan nice answer. Yeah. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that duplicate variable creation, what you need here is to change the member `cost`'s value to 55 or 50, it would be something like this.

```
// change the value of the cost member
newBook2.cost = 55;
```

Now once you will output this (in string notation) you will get the cost in the book. Until now, you're just initializing new variables, and not changing the value of the Book object's members. Let's say you get a book, and you want to change the properties of these objects, you can do so like the following code,

```
// create the object
Book myBook = new Book();

// now we will change the values for the members
myBook.title = "Databases R Us";
myBook.numInStock = 50;
myBook.cost = 50;
myBook.stockNum = 5555;

// Above were the settings for the Book object
System.out.print(myBook.toString());
```

The above code would have the properties that you've specified for the Book object and not the values for the variable. For more on class members, please go through this Java developer's link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: if i set it to myBook.title = "Databases R Us"; it says to change visibility of title from private to package

Comment: @adrianhmartinez, I am sorry but I didn't understand what you wanted to say. Can you please elaborate your intention? What is "item" here? class cannot have members that are wrapped in double qoutes.

Comment: oh i now got it it was myBook.settitle = "Databases R Us";

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BookDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a book named "Java is Fun" with 200 in stock costing 55.00 each.  The stock number is 1234
    Book javafun = new Book("Java is Fun", 200, 55.00, 1234);
    //print out the book using the toString() method
    System.out.println (javafun.toString());
    //create a book calling the empty constructor.
    Book newbook2 = new Book();

    //set the title to "Databases R Us"
    newbook2.setTitle("Databases R Us");
    //set the number in stock to 50
    newbook2.setNumInStock(50);
    // set the cost each to $35.00
    newbook2.setCost(35.00);
    // set the stock number to 5555
    newbook2.setStockNum(5555); 
    //print out the book.
    System.out.println(newbook2.toString());
    //change the price to $55.00
    newbook2.setCost(55.00);
    //print out the book
    System.out.println (newbook2.toString());
```